# With GIMP, how do I hide all layers except the current one?

Tags: gimp

Is there a way to hide all other layers when you click on the 'eye' symbol ? It's like what Macormedia Flash does , display only the layer that you click on , all else is hidden.

Is there a shortcut key ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Version 2.6**

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Click</kbd> on the eyeball, on the layer you want to remain visible.

**Version 2.8**

Installed from http://www.noobslab.com/2012/04/install-gimp-28-on-ubuntu-1204-precise.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Gimp 2.8 will still toggle visible layers using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the eyeball, but now with layers within *Layer Groups* Gimp will respect layers that are invisible, or visible within a Group, There is a discussion here by developers - [1](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gimp-developer-list/2012-May/msg00373.html)

What this means is that when you make a layer invisible within a group, it will stay invisible when toggling visibility of other layers and groups.

Before toggle and after toggle, I am toggling the visibility of the layer pointed to by the red arrow- 
[image]----------------[image]
Notice that the layer within the layer group stays invisible when toggling the other layers with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>

Now for the bad news, This also means that When trying to toggle the visibility of many layers *Within* a layer Group It does not work, only selecting the visibility of the group as a Whole,
[image]

Notice that I am toggling the visibility of the layer pointed to by the red arrow, yet only the layers outside the group are affected.

I have not found any workarounds for this behavior yet.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and unselect layers that you want to hide from the dialog box that appears.
This works in Gimp 2.8

Comment: how? It doesn't work for me, or I didn't do it the correct way